# How to check the docker-compose file version?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to make sure that I'm using version 3 of the compose file format. However, on https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ I was not able to find out how to do this.

My Docker version is `17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56`, and my Docker-Compose version is `docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387`. I'm not sure since when version 3 of the compose file format was introduced, however. How can I find this out?

Comment: docker compose version

Comment: docker compose version will tell you the version of docker compose and not the yml file version support

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's on your `docker-compose.yml` file. First parameter is Docker Compose version.

```
version: '3'
```

Docker Compose version file 3 was introduced in release 1.10.0 of Docker Compose and 1.13.0 release of Docker Engine.

Here you can see release notes for Docker Compose 1.10.0 which introduces version file 3: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.10.0

Comment: As I was still at docker-compose version 1.9.0, I did a `sudo pip install --upgrade docker-compose` to bump the version up to 1.12.0.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix

Answer (score 5):

The docker compose version 3 syntax requires docker version 1.13 and docker-compose version 1.10 ([see the release notes](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.10.0)). See the [release notes](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) for the version compatibility matrix and upgrade instructions.

Note that the version 3 syntax is designed for docker swarm mode, and it was first supported with the `docker stack deploy` in docker release 1.13. There's not much reason to upgrade to the version 3 syntax if you are still using `docker-compose` itself.

See also the [compose file versioning](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning) page that describes the differences between the different yml versions.

Comment: Docker themselves [discourage](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-top-level-element) specifying version at the top of `compose.yaml`.